# How can I seperate the page title into it's own component in liquid/shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to create a component / section for the hero using the `page.title` 
I have separated this out into a section with the following.

```
  <div class="contain--small">
    <h1 class="h1 hero__title text--center">{{ page.title }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then have included it into my page like this

`{% section 'hero' %}`

I cant see the page title on the page - the component is included and I can see it in the src when I check the CMS.
What am I missing here?
Do props need to be passed in or something? How can I do that?

Comment: Is this the only code in the section? If yes, there is no need for it to be a section, it can be just a snippet. In addition are using it only on pages since the `page` object is available only on pages and not on products/collections/blog etc...

Comment: Using liquid can you pass the page object to a snippet or section?

Comment: The `page` object is a GLOBAL object, you don't need to pass it. But the `page` object is ONLY available on `page` type pages ( fore example contact, faq, terms etc.. ). So if you are using it on other type of pages such as `product`, `collection`, `blog`, `article` etc... you won't have access to the page object. If you want the GLOBAL title for each type of page use  `{{ page_title }}` instead.